# I have to Export around 50 page pdf in node js which module i have to use?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-webkit, node-modules, sails.io.js

Currently I am using pdfmake module in my sails app to export pdf.But,when size of pdf increase it is taking too much time to export pdf,Ihave to export pdf of around 50 pages.So,Which module i can use to export pdf ? or any way to decrease load time in pdfmake module.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue with the performance of your server. Is it VPS, dedicated or somehow shared?

Try to use html-pdf
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf